# What does "in the Knight" mean in the following sentences?

Tags: meaning

What does "in the Knight" mean in the following sentences?
(Source: Princess Petunia's Sweet Apple Pie by Karen Poth)

> At midnight, someone knocked at the door. It was Bump **in the
>   Knight**. What could he want?

Does "It was Bump in the Knight" mean "It was Bump who wears a Knight costume" or "It was Bump who is a Knight"?
What does "in" of "in the Knight" mean?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Bump in the Knight" is his name. The in doesn't really have to mean anything, as it's part of a proper noun. It's like the town of Moreton-in-Marsh in the Cotswolds - that's the name of the town, so it doesn't really matter if it's actually in a marsh or not.

Comment: I have again edited the picture and I have added a picture where Bump is  the name of a man.

Comment: Yes, that's right. "Bump in the Knight" is his full name, or "Bump" for short.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase "a bump in the night" is a very standard phrase for "an unexpected sound" usually implying "of unknown origin" and possibly suggesting something at least mildly scary. A variant is "things that go bump in the night".

"It was Bump in the Knight." is almost surely punning or playing on this standard phrase. But whether it means that Bump wears a Knight outfit, or is a Knight, or perhaps works in a bar known as "the Knight" or something else cannot be determined without additional context. Without having read the source work, I cannot tell.

Comment: Yes. I have edited it. According to the story,  Bump is a man.